# Can I render Django template's format with if else condition using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax

I am using creating a Django application where I want to list down different products in the Django template by JS AJAX way. I just wonder how I can render it through js -

So I have two function one is for create the template for each product and here if you notice I have if else condition-

```
      function createTemplate(product) {
            return `<div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-45 hot sale">
                          <div class="single-product">
                            <div class="single-product__image">
                              <a class="image-wrap" href="{{product.get_absolute_url}">
                                <img src="{% if product.image %}
                                    {{ product.image.url }}
                                    {% else %}
                                    {% static 'img/no_image.png' %}
                                    {% endif %}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                              </a>
                              <div class="single-product__floating-icons">
                                <span class="wishlist">
                                  {% if product.id in wishlist_item_check  %}
                                  
                                  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="wishlistalready_${product.id}" data-tippy="Already Exists"
                                    data-tippy-inertia="true" data-tippy-animation="shift-away" data-tippy-delay="50"
                                    data-tippy-arrow="true" data-tippy-theme="sharpborder" data-tippy-placement="left"><i
                                      class="ion-android-favorite" style="color:red"></i></a>

                                  {% endif %}
                                </span>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>`;
          }
```

And another function to render all the products in a div with specific id (for example her id="products>"

```
      function renderProducts(products) {
            const template =
              products.length === 0
                ? `
                    <p>No matching results found.</p>
                    `
                : products.map((product) => createTemplate(product)).join('\n');
            $('#products').html(template);
          }
```

Lastly I am rendering all the products in a div

```
<div class="row" id="products">
```

Do let me know if we any better and easy way of doing the same.

Comment: Hi , what does product has in it ? Can you show output of it ?

Comment: Hi @Swati. Here products is an array of product which I am getting from the Django backend. Each product has multiple fields for example id, name, price, image etc etc.

Comment: I see so here you are talking about this--> `{% if product.id in wishlist_item_check  %}..` ?

Comment: href="{{product.get_absolute_url}" let's just consider this only. Do you have any idea how to render django template code through ajax call

Comment: Just generate html code inside success fn of ajax. Your `product` is response which you are getting inside ajax call ? If yes update your question with output as well so that i can provide you solution.